# How to properly unlock an FFC connector?

Tags: ribbon-cable, ffc, zif

I'm trying to replace a part on my camera and need to disconnect a connector that looks like this:

[image: FFC Connector]

From what I understand, they're extremely fragile and so I don't want to accidentally break anything (as many others unfortunately did when working on this camera).

Whats the correct way to unlock this connector?

Which part of the connector unlocks? The bottom or the top part?

Comment: Does the light grey flap at the bottom as pictured (away from the ribbon) lift up? Try a gentle manipulation with a little flat head screwdriver to see if it flicks up - if it's going to it won't take much force to do so.

Comment: Although labeled as `zif` there are also non-zif ffc connectors, from which you just pull out. If you pull a little on the cable and it comes off, then it is not a zif connector.

Answer (score 1):

The black plastic portion is hinged. Very gently lift it up with small tweezers or a jeweler's screwdriver, taking care not to open it beyond the range of the small hinges on which it pivots.

Some other flat flex ribbon cable connectors pull out to unlock and push in to lock. You just have to inspect them carefully.